# Retriving Data from google Map App to our ios app

Tags: ios, google-maps-api-3, url-scheme

I have a question about Google maps App url Scheme. We are building one Transit Direction App, In our app we are opening Google Map App using callback request. up to to this everything is ok we can open that app and come back to our app successfully.
       But I want that when we are coming back to our app I want data from Google Map App i.e. user searched direction data or any state data from where user came back to my App.

Thanks And Regards
Ashwini

Answer (score 0):

You can use the x-callback request to come back to your app with additional parameters like this,

```
comgooglemaps-x-callback:////x-callback-url/open/?url=<var>URL-Scheme-Parameters</var>&<i>parameters</i>
```

opening the above scheme with your app's uri scheme would open your app on completion of google map app's intended operation but getting data from the google map app is not possible.

See below links for sample code.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme

http://x-callback-url.com/